# ng build and ng build --prod not loading style or script files

Tags: angular

In my application I can able to build and do the prodution build but when I try to run those version getting the error in the console.

style or script files faild to load .
@angular/cli": "~9.1.1",

Please see the image[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLe6r.png)

THanks

Comment: so you're running this?

`ng build --prod` →
`cd dist/browser` →
`http-server .`
or how are you running your local http server (localhost:5000) as your image suggests? have you tried disabling caching in the console? maybe index.html is cached with old js chunk names

Answer (score 0):

It looks that you do **not properly configured your deployment sever**. When you build, you are not using Angular-CLI anymore. Your shuld be using a Server (like, for example, Apache or Nginx). And, in that given server environment, you need to enable rewrite rules; otherwise it will not work and you get 404 errors (as you show).

Take a look to Angular's deployment guide: https://angular.io/guide/deployment#server-configuration They give you file examples depending on server type.